# Ruby parser in Java

Tags: java, ruby, parsing, jruby

The project I'm doing is written in Java and parsers source code files. (Java src up to now). Now I'd like to enable parsing Ruby code as well.
Therefore I am looking for a parser in Java that parses Ruby source code.

The only thing I have been able to find up to now are Ruby parsers in Ruby (ParseTree and RubyParser...).
I could maybe parse the source files I want with a Ruby parser in JRuby, and then access my Java stuff from there.
But that would mean that I will not be able to reuse a lot of my previously written Java code.

Is there a decent Ruby parser in Java out there and have I just not be able to find it? Or does someone see a better solution?

Comment: this is relevant for me. did you find anything?

Comment: Huh, you found an old question of mine. :) I worked on this during my bachelors thesis... Sadly I never found an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See http://kenai.com/projects/jruby-parser/

Comment: Nice. Stumbled upon that before but the repo was down at the time and I feared the project was dead. Looks nice at the first glance, definitley a good start. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could let ANTLR generate a lexer/parser for you. They have a simplified Ruby grammar available: http://www.antlr.org/grammar/1160820213459/rubyParserLexerSPGrammar.g which may be sufficient for your needs.