# ruby parser in java?

Tags: ruby, jruby

I am looking for a ruby parser (that hopefully supports the latest version of ruby if possible). Has there been any success in ripping out the parser from JRuby as a standalone tool?

Alternatively, I am also interested in independent efforts in building Ruby parsers in Java. There has been an earlier post on this: [Ruby parser in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1728638/ruby-parser-in-java)

Has there been any updates?

Comment: why not just use jruby as it is, rather than ripping out it's parser standalone? Probably because you want a smaller dependency. I think your best chance of success is probably just using jruby though.

Answer (score 0):

See https://github.com/whitequark/parser

(which is the first hit when i google for "ruby parser")